# using HW random number generator as source of entropy

Tags: random, entropy, haveged

Currently I am using `haveged` on my server as source of entropy.

My Server is used as KVM hypervisor, to run virtual machines.

I did not use `haveged` at the beginning, and I noticed the VMs were draining the entropy pool from the server. Sometimes, when VMs were started SSH waited for enough entropy (to generate session keys, I guess).

Now with `haveged`, I don't have this problem anymore.

But I would like to try to use a HW random number generator. I am not saying `haveged` is bad, but true HW random number generator can only make the entropy better. 
I have seen some HW RNG which work on basis of Geiger counter, some which collect noise from microphone, and so on.

Which are most reasonable to use ?
Could somebody perhaps recommend some specific one ?

Ideally, I would like it to be connected over serial port. Second best would be over USB.

Comment: Doesn't the processor on your host have a random generator built in (RDRAND)?

Comment: @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil' - I think the processor has RNG, but linux does not use it.

Answer (score -1):

Haveged has already been contested and does not guarantee TRNG.

You should get a hardware certified device like [QRNG](https://www.idquantique.com/random-number-generation/products/quantis-random-number-generator/) . 
It is a certified device and has passed many compliance tests including NIST SP800-22.

You can also find an [USB stick device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01KR2JHTA) which claims it passes tests like Dieharder, ENT, Rngtest, FIPS-140-2.

These 2 should definitely be better than Haveged.

Other things you mentioned like Geiger or noise are also determinable/predictable.

Comment: "Geiger or noise are also determinable/predictable." I would like to know how Geiger is predictable.For noise, it depends on what kind of system you're imagining.

Comment: Sources used like an Americium 241 pellet have very determinable output. Unless you work in a lab with hundreds of different sources, you will be able to determine a Geiger's response.

Comment: Citation needed on your claims about haveged (not in VMs) and Geiger counters.

Comment: You may be able to determine the general rate of decay, but it is fundamentally impossible to predict a (sensitive) Geiger's response with sufficient precision to make it useless as an entropy source.